# DB Connection via windows Service Account in JAVA Spring MVC using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat9, dbconnection

I am unable to acquire Connection via windows Service Account in JAVA Spring MVC using Hibernate.
There's no error while deploying one application.  I am facing below issue while deploying multiple applications in same tomcat.
To more on this

1. I am using one tomcat instance.
2. I am using hibernate to create session factory
3. I am use windows service to start the tomcat (Provided DB windows service account to start the service)
4. While deploying one application its working fine
5. While deploying multiple application its giving deadlock issue.

Comment: Just wondering, is the connection pool another instance of a pool per webapp or a site configured global for all webapps? You may be able to solve it by a common global connection pool in the server.xml. Other than that , the SQL table requires row level locking to prevent dirty read, hibernate con pool in server.xml , example of where.   https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/odm/8.10?topic=tomcat-step-1-creating-data-source-connection-pool          The following is a better article on that problem.    https://shekhargulati.com/2020/06/17/how-to-solve-database-deadlock-on-microsoft-sql-server/

Comment: That type of concurrency issue occurs more with the SQL server and tomcat assigned multiple cores. Tomcat has some thread concurrency settings can be put into the server.xml also. But if you call through a servlet, in dopost() or doget() it may be assistance to build "helper class" to instantiate into a synchronized block object locking it also. Helper class is another new class (source in servlet folder pak) not extended with the servlet so call the results from the processing in the helper.

Comment: And if that continued, there is one mad (obscure) one to check, the chipset board and components BUS speeds could be badly matched for their ratings! Usually an ultra cheap featured machine.

Comment: And check also your servlet uses either SingleThreadModel or has a filter class configured with a synchronized object block to the servlet configured in the web.xml (latter is the up to date method)